# How to create a child domain in server 2008 without providing its Root name as suffix

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to create a child domain in server 2008. For creating the child domain the naming convention is to give its Root name as a suffix. If your Root domain name is `domainA.com` then you have to give the child name as `domainB.domainA.com`.

What I want is to create a child domain `domainB.com` and not by its convention `domainB.domainA.com`.

Thanks,
Asif

Comment: I believe it may be more than just "convention".

Comment: Do you have any better option?

Comment: Why do you need it as a child domain? Why not just create it as a separate domain and establish required trust(s) between them?

Comment: Thanks for reply, If I go like this then Do i get the same functionality ant relation that exist between the child and parent?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this.

Let me know if it is of any use.

http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/server-2008-active-directory-adding-a-child-domain

Regards

Ashutosh

Comment: Doesn't appear to address the main thrust of the OPs question, which is to avoid having the child domain being a subdomain of the parent.

Comment: Hi Ashutosh i gone through the link that you posted. But i did not find anything according to my requirement.